# Excel 2016 UserForm

Tags: vba, macros, microsoft-excel-2016

Ok, I have a userform. On this user form I have a combo box that pulls its data from a worksheet called "Lists" (Range A2:A49).  I have three text boxes Purchasing_Group "Lists" worksheet (Range D2:D49), Plant_Number "Lists" (Range B2:B49), and Profit_Center "Lists" (Range E2:E49) combo box.

I need the three text boxes to auto-fill based on the choice from the combo box. [image]

Comment: Please note that https://superuser.com is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this should work, at least it does in Excel 2011.

In the code below, "ComboResult" is the output of your Combo box (the "cell link").  It has to be entered as a cell reference in double quotes, i.e. "C7".

Similarly "LookupTable" is the range of cells in your plant table, i.e "A1:E50". Again, double quotes.  I'm assuming your lookup table is on Sheet2.  You can use a named sheet by using Sheets("sheet name").Range().

Because the Combo box outputs a number (the position of the user's choice in the list), your lookup table must have an index column as the first column.  It will just be 1,2,3 etc. up to the number of plants in the list.

```
Sub FillTextbox()
  'Set up variables
    Dim TextboxName As String
    Dim TextboxText As String
    Dim Line1Text As String
    Dim Line2Text As String
    Dim Line3Text As String
  'Assemble the text
    Line1Text = "Plant Number: " &
       Sheet2.Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Range("ComboResult"),
       Sheet2.Range("LookupTable"), 3, False)
    Line2Text = "Purchasing Group: " &
       Sheet2.Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Range("ComboResult"),
       Sheet2.Range("LookupTable"), 4, False)
    Line3Text = "Profit Center: " &
       Sheet2.Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Range("ComboResult"),
       Sheet2.Range("LookupTable"), 5, False)
    TextboxText = Line1Text & vbNewLine & Line2Text & vbNewLine & Line3Text
  'Fill the Textbox
    TextboxName = "TextBox 1"
    ActiveSheet.Shapes(TextboxName).DrawingObject.Text = TextboxText
End Sub
```

After adding the index column, the data you want will be in columns 3,4 and 5 of the table, and the vlookup functions grab those values, based on the index chosen in the Combo box.

Comment: Is it possible to do what I need?

Comment: Yes.  Create the vba module above and then assign it to the Combo box.  Anytime the Combo box changes, the text box will get the new data.

Comment: Note:  I wrote this code in Word and then got funky errors after pasting it into Excel.  Turned out Excel doesn't like the quote characters that Word uses.  Their "smart quotes", I think.  I had to delete all the quotes and then retype.  Sheesh.  I guess if I had converted to plain text, it would have been OK.

Comment: @R.Conklin -
Edit your original question.  Paste in some snippets of code.  If you put 4 spaces at the start of each line, the site will automatically format it as code.

Can you see my answer with the subroutine?  Since this question was put on hold, I'm not sure if my answer made it.

Comment: Ok.  I see you have 3 different text boxes to fill.  Edit the code above and add two more ActiveSheet.Shapes statements that reference the other two text boxes.

Comment: I can see everything that has been posted.  I am currently modifying the code.  I know you said that the "ComboResult" has to reference a cell link and be in double quotes, but what cell am I looking for?  I have 49 bakeries, each one has a unique Plant Number, Purchasing Group, and Profit Center.

Comment: Right-click on the Combo box and choose "Format Control".  There you specify the range that contains the list of values to be displayed and the cell that holds the output.

When you pick an item in the list, it's number will appear in the cell you specified.  That's the "ComboResult".  It can be hidden on another sheet if you need it to be.  Enter that cell into the Vlookup statements.

Comment: i do not have that option, see the pic that I posted above.

Comment: Depending on your version of Excel, this should explain hoe to set the input range and cell link:

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Add-a-list-box-or-combo-box-to-a-worksheet-in-Excel-579e1958-f7f6-41ae-ba0c-c83cc6e40878

And I think you'll find it under "Properties" in your pic.

Comment: In newer versions of Excel, the list is specified in "List Fill Range" and the output in "Linked Cell".
http://www.contextures.com/excelworksheetcomboboxes.html

Comment: I looked at your link last night.  It explains perfectly how to do everything when the combo box is in an excel worksheet, but not it a userform like mine is.  I posted the code that I currently have in my user form above.  I keep getting a compile error in my noun_combobox line.

Comment: The error you're getting is actually caused by the following line.  You can't have two subroutines in one module.

  For testing and debugging, I suggest you divide your code up into smaller sections and run each one.

  The debugger can help:
https://www.techonthenet.com/excel/macros/vba_debug2013.php

  You can also insert a line of code that will give you a popup message to notify you that sections ran successfully:

  MsgBox("Section 1 OK")

Comment: @R.Conklin, if you found my answer and comments helpful, please award me points.  See this link:

[link](https://superuser.com/help/someone-answers)